# spring orm exception when spring orm added to pom.xml

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I am new to spring development and I tried to add maven dependency for spring orm, in the pom.xml file it gives the following exception when the server starts. Also when I remove that dependency, the exception goes. Can you please tell me what is wrong with this.

Thanks.

```
SEVERE: Unable to process Jar entry [org/springframework/orm/jpa/JpaObjectRetrievalFailureException.class] from Jar [jar:file:/home/madhumal/mavenproj/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp0/wtpwebapps/NurseryApplication/WEB-INF/lib/spring-orm-3.1.2.RELEASE.jar!/] for annotations
org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid constant pool reference: 99. Constant pool size is: 25
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.getConstant(ConstantPool.java:184)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ConstantPool.getConstant(ConstantPool.java:203)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.SourceFile.getSourceFileName(SourceFile.java:92)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.JavaClass.<init>(JavaClass.java:122)
```

below is my pom.xml file.

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>mad.maventest2.app</groupId>
    <artifactId>NurseryApplication</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>NurseryApplication</name>

    <properties>
        <spring.version>3.1.2.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.6.Final</hibernate.version>
    </properties>


    <dependencies>

        <!-- Spring 3 dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring Security -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>



        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${hibernate.version}</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <!-- <dependency> -->
        <!-- <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId> -->
        <!-- <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId> -->
        <!-- <version>${hibernate.version}</version> -->
        <!-- </dependency> -->

        <!-- other dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.6</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                    <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                    <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                    <wtpversion>1.5</wtpversion>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`org.apache.tomcat.util.bcel.classfile.ClassFormatException: Invalid constant pool reference: 99. Constant pool size is: 25`

Looks like something is wrong with the jar file. -- Delete it from your local m2. repository and maven will download it again. I hope this fixes the problem.